# What causes the following linking error with CMake and Imagemagick library?

Tags: cmake, linker, imagemagick, linker-errors

I have a main.cpp file that includes a header file from the same directory where I have used the boost library, magickimage c++ library, and eigen library. Here is my CMakeLists.txt file where I have linked the .lib and .a files to my target and set the includer paths.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.2)
project(blackjackAI)
add_executable(blackjackAI main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(blackjackAI PRIVATE C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++/c++Dep/boost_1_77_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-gcc10-mt-x64-1_77.a)
target_link_libraries(blackjackAI PRIVATE C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++/c++Dep/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI/lib/CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib)
target_link_libraries(blackjackAI PRIVATE C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++/c++Dep/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI/lib/CORE_RL_MagickCore_.lib)
target_link_libraries(blackjackAI PRIVATE C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++/c++Dep/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI/lib/CORE_RL_MagickWand_.lib)
target_include_directories(blackjackAI PRIVATE C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++/c++Dep/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI/include)
target_include_directories(blackjackAI PRIVATE C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++/c++Dep/eigen-3.4.0)
target_include_directories(blackjackAI PRIVATE C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++/c++Dep/boost_1_77_0)
target_include_directories(blackjackAI PRIVATE C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++/blackjackAI)
```

For some reason when I compile my CMakeLists.txt file with the "MinGW Makefiles" generator and then use the makefile I get the following linker error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles\blackjackAI.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:\Users\Ejer
\Desktop\c++\blackjackAI\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN6CnnNetC1ESs[_ZN6CnnNetC1ESs]+0x3dd): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::Image()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles\blackjackAI.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:\Users\Ejer
\Desktop\c++\blackjackAI\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN6CnnNetC1ESs[_ZN6CnnNetC1ESs]+0x413): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::read(std::str
ing const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles\blackjackAI.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:\Users\Ejer
\Desktop\c++\blackjackAI\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN6CnnNetC1ESs[_ZN6CnnNetC1ESs]+0x436): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::type(MagickCo
re::ImageType)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles\blackjackAI.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:\Users\Ejer
\Desktop\c++\blackjackAI\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN6CnnNetC1ESs[_ZN6CnnNetC1ESs]+0x45b): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles\blackjackAI.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:\Users\Ejer
\Desktop\c++\blackjackAI\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN6CnnNetC1ESs[_ZN6CnnNetC1ESs]+0x539): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles\blackjackAI.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:\Users\Ejer
\Desktop\c++\blackjackAI\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN6Magick5ImageEE9constructIS2_JRKS2_EEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZN9__gnu_cxx1
3new_allocatorIN6Magick5ImageEE9constructIS2_JRKS2_EEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x46): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::Image(Magick::Image co
nst&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles\blackjackAI.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:\Users\Ejer
\Desktop\c++\blackjackAI\main.cpp:(.text$_ZSt10_ConstructIN6Magick5ImageEJRKS1_EEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZSt10_ConstructIN6Magick5ImageEJRKS1_EEvP
T_DpOT0_]+0x42): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::Image(Magick::Image const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\blackjackAI.dir\build.make:102: recipe for target 'blackjackAI.exe' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [blackjackAI.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/blackjackAI.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/blackjackAI.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:89: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It says that I have undefined references to the use of the Image class in my header file, even though I have linked my includer path and .lib files in CMakeLists.txt file and my main.cpp file to the imagemagick library. What is causing the problem?

Comment: It looks like you're using the GNU toolchain, but trying to link to a MSVC-style .lib library.  That won't work.  You'll need the correct version of the ImageMagick library for your platform.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I have tried looking for the right version on their site but I cant find any that is for windows and suitable for the GNU toolchain, here is the site: https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php There are some for linux but I dont think that will work with windows. Can you maybe tell me if I have missed something or what I should be looking for. Thanks in advance

Comment: Under Linux Releases there are both Cygwin and MinGW builds.  If you're using cygwin it also has libMagick-Devel packages in its repo that you could use.  Those look like they're for linking dynamically though, so may not be appropriate if you want to statically link to the library.

Comment: @MilesBudnek But how can It run on windows when it is made for linux?

Comment: Because ImageMagick's downloads page is poorly labeled.  Cygwin and MinGW are Unix-like environments built on top of Windows.  They really are their own things and shouldn't be lumped into the Linux section like that.